# Image registration of aerial image

Tags: opencv, registration

Say I have 2 aerial photos taken by unmanned small planes(Actually I have a few aerial videos..thats a lot of photos). The images are taken from the same area but from different angles and heights. Any ideas on how to match them together?

I used `SIFT` to get match points from 2 images, and got about 250 matched paries.Then I used `RANSAC` to cut down the number to approximately 150 matched points.But I don't no how to warp one image to the other?

Currently I use `cvWarpPerspective()` and `cvWarpImage()` in `OpenCV`, but `cvWarpPerspective()` only needs 4 paires of points for image registration. And the result is not really exact. And I still have more than 146 points unused.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find Homography matrix using OpenCV's `findHomography` function.

```
Mat H;
H = findHomography(homographyPoints1, homographyPoints2, CV_LMEDS);
warpPerspective(img1, oimg1, H, img1.size(), INTER_NEAREST);
```

Warp both images and you will get two output images. You can use all 150 points in this. Push your matched 150 keypoints in homographyPoints1 and homographyPoints2 (or some other vector) and use `CV_LMEDS`. `CV_RANSAC` will randomly select 4 to 8 points and compute the homography which might be inaccurate.